# How to read this XML with that has HTML tags with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have been working several times with php and XML but this kind of XML has Html tags in the beginning and in the end:

[Link To XML](https://www.tandildiario.com/suscripcion.php?section=5)

there is no direct link to the xml file so I have to use file_get_contents().

Im using this php code:

```
 $url = "https://www.tandildiario.com/suscripcion.php?section=4";
 $xml   = file_get_contents($url);
 $feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);

  foreach ($feed->channel->item as $item) {
  .....
```

I try different thing ..most of the errors are like this:

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 14: parser error : Entity 'oacute' not defined in D:\reader.php on line 37

Comment: That XML is not correct. If you're gonna have HTML data in XML, it should be wrapped in [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) tags. Otherwise, the parser will try to parse the HTML as XML. Where does the XML come from?

Comment: is from a newspaper...not mine, I just have to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could decode the HTML entities prior to loading the XML.

```
$url = "https://www.tandildiario.com/suscripcion.php?section=5";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$feed = simplexml_load_string(html_entity_decode($xml, null, "UTF-8"));

foreach ( $feed->channel->item as $item )   {
    echo $item->asXML();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original XML is incorrect (it contains unescaped HTML in the description-tags), you can fix it before trying to parse it. Add the CDATA-attributes yourself:

```
$url = "https://www.tandildiario.com/suscripcion.php?section=4";
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

// Add the CDATA tags for the description
$xml = str_replace('<description>', '<description><![CDATA[', $xml);
$xml = str_replace('</description>', ']]></description>', $xml);

$feed = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```